# Não estou conseguindo fazer o programa retornar a maior e a menor média

Tags: python

[image: o arquivo deve ter o conteúdo da imagem]

**O problema é esse:**
Escreva um programa que lê um arquivo chamado notas.txt que contém em cada linha o nome de
um aluno e quatro notas entre 0 e 100. O programa deve então exibir na tela a maior e a menor média
dentre todos os alunos.
**Meu código é esse:**

```
arquivo = open('notas.txt')
for linha in arquivo:
    notas = linha[4:]
    soma = 0
    for nota in notas.split():
        soma=soma+int(nota)
    media = soma / 4
    print(media)

arquivo.close()
```

Comment: Olá @nicole-askar da uma olhada neste exemplo [aqui](https://ideone.com/QoFTdA) ele pode ser melhorado, mais já vai te dar um norte.

Comment: Nicole Askar, teste esse [exemplo](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/Media#main.py)

Comment: https://replit.com/@hkotsubo/Media#main.py

Answer (score -4):

A resposta para este problema é a seguinte:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    arquivo = open('notas.txt', 'r')
    notas = []
    medias = []

    for linha in arquivo:
        campos = linha.split(' ')
        nome = campos[0]
        notas = []
        for nota in campos[1:]:
            notas.append(int(nota))
            media = sum(notas)/len(notas)
        medias.append(media)
        maior_media = max(medias)
        menor_media = min(medias)
    print(f'{maior_media:.2f}')
    print(f'{menor_media:.2f}') 
    arquivo.close()
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).